# How to implement 360 video player in ionic v1 App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I want to implement 360 video player within my App, for that i have tried this plugin https://github.com/ashtonlance/ionic-vr/tree/generic-multivideo/www/components. 
        I have successfully implemented this plugin but sometimes its not loading video.

```
how to integrate 360 video player perfectly?
```